# ReactJs Environment variables form NestJS

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, nestjs

We are working on a reactjs web application with NestJs for server-side.

At the moment we use `ServeStaticModule.forRoot`.

The app needs some configuration (e.g. url of analytics server, clientId, redirectUrl …).

Since Create React App doesn’t support server rendering, we added placeholders into the HTML and we want to inject variables to the client.

For example :

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script>
      window.CONFIG = __CONFIG__;
    </script>
```

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/title-and-meta-tags#generating-dynamic-meta-tags-on-the-server

How can we replace the **CONFIG**?

Answer (score 0):

The following approach is for Express.

If you want to modify `index.html` then one approach is to use `app.useStaticAsset(//build path, {index: false})` in `main.ts` to serve the content while ignoring `index.html`. Then you can `sendFile(//index.html path)` in root path to deliver a page.

To replace placeholder config, you can have something like `readFileAsync` in a respective service or controller to read `index.html` content and process it before delivering to a client.